# Send only pinned tabs in VisualStudio 2013 with Productivity Power Tools?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, productivity-power-tools

Can be possible to put only pinned tabs to the vertical left and the other tabs on the top in `VisualStudio 2013` with `Productivity Power Tools`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no, either if one has tabs which reside on the left vertical side, the pinned tabs are organized at the top. Or if the tabs reside along the top, all pinned tabs are placed on the left.

One cannot have pinned tabs in the `left` side (and descending) while all other pinned tabs are along the top and horizontal.

Interesting idea though.